# How could I fetch the string in the brackets

Tags: python

I tried `re.match(r"[\'(.*?)\']", data)`

But I got no luck

```
# input string value

"['WBAI@lalal']"

# expected output string

"WBAI@lalal"
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Is that input a list with a string as element? Or is it that entire input a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you forgot to escape the brackets. The [ and ] are used to denote character classes in regex. `re.match(r"\[\'(.*?)\'\]", data)` will get you what you're asking for, but this does not look like the best way to do whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the string starts with `['` and ends with `']`, then you can just extract the content directly:

```
>>> s = "['WBAI@lalal']"
>>> s[2:-2]
'WBAI@lalal'
```